# Getting selected item from Telerik Combobox in edit mode of Grid?

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

So I have a combobox within the edit form of a grid... when I select update I want to get the selected item from the combobox and if it represents a change I would execute an update.  For the life of me... and I admit to being terribly rusty, I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.  I also tried reading it in a selectionchanged event and that doesn't fire :C

As always, I am deeply grateful for anyone that can spare the time to point me in the right direction... here are my most recent of many manyyyy attempts.

```
protected void RadGrid1_UpdateCommand(object source, GridCommandEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.CommandName == "Update")
        {

            GridEditableItem item = (GridEditableItem)e.Item;           
            RadComboBox combo =(RadComboBox)item.FindControl("updateComboBox");             
            var status = (string)item.GetDataKeyValue("status");
            if (combo.SelectedItem.Text!= status)

            {
                //do my update                
            }


        }
```

Edited to add ASPX:

```
  <telerik:GridTemplateColumn HeaderText="Category" ItemStyle-Width="240px">

                    <ItemTemplate>

                        <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Status")%>

                    </ItemTemplate>

                    <EditItemTemplate>

                        <telerik:RadComboBox RenderMode="Lightweight" runat="server" ID="updateComboBox" DataTextField="Status" 

                            DataValueField="ID" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource1" SelectedValue='<%#Bind("ID") %>' AutoPostBack="False" EnableLoadOnDemand="True" CausesValidation="False">

                        </telerik:RadComboBox>

                    </EditItemTemplate>

                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                <telerik:GridEditCommandColumn FooterText="EditCommand footer" UniqueName="EditCommandColumn"

                    HeaderText="Edit" HeaderStyle-Width="100px" UpdateText="Update">
```

```
                </telerik:GridEditCommandColumn>
```

Comment: Where exactly is the problem? Is the combobox configured to load items on demand?

Comment: @VeselinVasilev... well, the "big" problem, basically, is that I'm unable to read the combobox selected text.  I've been trying to follow the examples Telerik gives and have no luck.  All I can get is the first (default) value.  If I set to auto postback, it "resets" immediately after I select a value from the dropdown and if I leave it set to not postback, it still retrieves the original value, not the selected value.

Comment: If you have enabled LoadOnDemand of the combobox then you should only use SelectedValue and Text properties on the server.

See this article: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/combobox/troubleshooting/radcombobox-items-are-not-accessible-on-the-server-side-when-loading-them-on-demand

Comment: To better understand your problem, please include your ASPX markup in your post.

Comment: @VeselinVasilev 
Thank you for your replies... sorry I got diverted today.  I edited my original post to add the relevant section of my markup.  As I tried to explain, no matter what I try I am unable to read the selected text.  I've tried making the combobox auto postback or not, load on demand, tried catching it in the selecteditemchanged event (which doesn't seem to fire at all).  I've tried a dozen different approaches and getting nowhere... I'd be very grateful for any suggestions!

Thank you!

Comment: @woodykiddy Thank you for your reply... sorry I got diverted today. I edited my original post to add the relevant section of my markup. As I tried to explain, no matter what I try I am unable to read the selected text. I've tried making the combobox auto postback or not, load on demand, tried catching it in the selecteditemchanged event (which doesn't seem to fire at all). I've tried a dozen different approaches and getting nowhere... I'd be very grateful for any suggestions! Thank you! –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I feel like an idiot but perhaps this will help someone else with the same problem.  I was calling databinding at an inappropriate place.  Seems like that fixed it...

Thank you to the people who offered input, best wishes!